# Probability question with a radio competition

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm quite new to statistics and I'm going through a few exam questions but I am a bit stuck on this one:

```
A radio station held a competition where contestants were invited to pick a
number from 1 to 50. If a contestant picked the ‘winning’ number they won a
trip to Vegas. The station picked a new ‘winning’ number at random each time
a new contestant played the game. The radio station allowed five contestants
to play every day over the course of one week.

    i. Compute the probability that the station will have to pay out for exactly 
one Vegas trip.
    ii. Compute the probability that the station will have to pay out for more
than 2 Vegas trips.
    iii. Suppose that the station decides to run the competition for an entire year
giving 5 × 365 = 1825 contestants. Find the approximate probability that
the number of Vegas trips they will have to pay for is greater than 50.
```

I'm not sure how to go about calculating this one and as I stated above I'm new to statistics so I'm not very good at it. Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: The Information given in the exam are not quite complete: it isn't said how the radio station draws there winning number. But if you assume it is a uniform distribution, the umber of sucesses are binomial distributed.

Comment: @Qaswed Thanks for your reply! So I just use Binomial Distribution formula and work it out? what about the last part how do I compute that?

Comment: In the last part I'm guessing you're supposed to use the Poisson on normal approximation, depending on the context of the problem in your course and whether you are using statistical software. For the normal, $\mu = np = 1825(1/50)$ and $\sigma = \sqrt{np(1-p)}.$ See computations in my Answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Compute the probability that the station will have to pay out for exactly 
>   one trip:

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{1}\binom{35}{n}\cdot\left(\frac{1}{50}\right)^{n}\cdot\left(1-\frac{1}{50}\right)^{35-n}$$

> Compute the probability that the station will have to pay out for more
>   than $2$ trips:

$$\sum\limits_{n=3}^{35}\binom{35}{n}\cdot\left(\frac{1}{50}\right)^{n}\cdot\left(1-\frac{1}{50}\right)^{35-n}$$

Comment: The first display simplifies to ${35 \choose 1}(1/50)(49/50)^{34} = 0.3522.$ In the second, there is less computation if you use the complement: $ 1 - \sum_{i=0}^2 {35 \choose i}(1/50)^i(49/50)^{35-i},$ in which you need to sum only three terms.

Comment: @BruceET: True, but I wanted to keep it as simple as possible for the OP (i.e., a single type of formula).

Answer (score 0):

In the first two parts, the number $X$ of contestants winning trips is 
$X \sim Binom(35, 1/5).$ Here are partial PDF and CDF 4-place tables of that
distribution from R. Compare
your computed answers from the binomial formula with appropriate entries.

```
 n = 35;  p = 1/50;  i = 0:5
 pdf = round(dbinom(i, n, p), 4)
 cdf = round(pbinom(i, n, p), 4)
 cbind(i, pdf, cdf)
      i    pdf    cdf
      0 0.4931 0.4931
      1 0.3522 0.8453       
      2 0.1222 0.9675
      3 0.0274 0.9949      
      4 0.0045 0.9994
      5 0.0006 0.9999
```

For the last part you have $Y \sim Binom(1825, 1/50),$ and you
seek $P(Y > 50).$ Results below are for the exact binomial value
(perhaps too tedious to compute by hand), and Poisson and normal
approximations.

```
 n = 1825; p = 1/50;  mu = n*p;  sg = sqrt(n*p*(1-p))
 1 - pbinom(50, n, p)
 ## 0.01257754
 1 - ppois(50, mu)
 ## 0.01338316
 1 - pnorm(50.5, mu, sg)
 ## 0.009620645
```

The figure below shows the PDF of $Binom(1825, 1/50)$ (black bars),
and the Poisson approximation (blue open circles) and the
best-fitting normal curve (red curve).

[image]